# Facing error while using EventListener

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using EventListener first time but facing below exception. Please can any one help on the same.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at seleniumTest.EventListener.beforeFindBy(EventListener.java:62)

```
package seleniumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;


public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebElement element ;
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        EventListener listener = new EventListener();

        eventDriver.register(listener);
        eventDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        eventDriver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
//      element = eventDriver.findElement(By.id("sb_ifc0"));
//      element.sendKeys("Shantaveer");
        element = eventDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type= 'submit']"));
        element.click();

    }

}

    package seleniumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener;

public class EventListener implements WebDriverEventListener{

    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("inside method afterChangeValueOf on " + arg0.toString());
    }

    public void afterClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("inside method afterClickOn on " + arg0.toString());
    }

    public void afterFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Find happened on " + arg1.toString() 
                + " Using method " + arg0.toString());
    }

    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside the after navigateback to " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());
    }

    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside the afterNavigateForward to " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());
    }

    public void afterNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside the afterNavigateTo to " + arg0);
    }

    public void afterScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside the afterScript to, Script is " + arg0);
    }

    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside the beforeChangeValueOf method");
    }

    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("About to click on the " + arg0.toString());

    }

    public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Just before finding element " + arg1.toString());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Just before beforeNavigateBack " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Just before beforeNavigateForward " + arg0.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Just before beforeNavigateTo " + arg0);
    }

    public void beforeScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Just before beforeScript " + arg0);
    }

    public void onException(Throwable arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Exception occured at " + arg0.getMessage());

    }


    @Override
    public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the similar [issue 1589](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1589):

> When implementing `beforeFindBy` and `afterFindBy` methods on `WebDriverEventListener` interface, we obtain `NullPointerException`.
>   The `webElement` is not passed to the listener. by object is correctly passed.

The [documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html#beforeFindBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver-) does mention:

```
void beforeFindBy(By by,
                  WebElement element,
                  WebDriver driver)
```

> Called before `WebDriver.findElement(...)`, or `WebDriver.findElements(...)`, or `WebElement.findElement(...)`, or `WebElement.findElements(...)`.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `element` - **will be null, if a find method of `WebDriver` is called**.

The [author lukeis](https://github.com/lukeis) commented [in the issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1589#issuecomment-180468939):

> The intent of the `WebElement` parameter is to show the element used as a reference to `findBy`, not the found element(s).
>
> `WebElement` is not null when we use `findElement` apart from `WebDriver`, such as using `findElement` method of `WebElement`.

So you should protect Webelement arg1: it can be null, as documented.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. I could not understand reason and how to solve the same.

Comment: @user3415045 I don't have much beside the documentation here: I suspect `eventDriver.findElement()` calls `beforeFind()` in which `WebElement` (your arg1) is `null`. So don't call a `toString()` on a null element.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same just after I texted you. Now its working.